# Print wrong value of unsigned int variable in C

Tags: c

I have written this small program using C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned int un_i = 1112;
    printf ("%d and %d", (1 - un_i), (1 - un_i)/10);
    return 0;
}
```

My expectation is: "-1111 and -111"

But my result is: "-1111 and 429496618"

I don't know why it prints out 429496618 instead of -111. Please explain for me

I use gcc ver 4.4.7 and OS centos with kernel 2.6.32

Thank you very much!

Comment: It is `unsigned`, don't expect it to be signed. And to print it correctly use `%u` not `%d`.

Comment: `printf ("PRINTF: un_i[%d] and u_i/10[%d]\n", (int)(1 - un_i), (int)(1 - un_i)/10);`

Comment: The `%d` format expects an `int` (signed), not an `unsigned`.   A mismatch between the format specifier and type of the corresponding argument gives undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

That because `un_i` is of type `unsigned int`, it does not represent negative values. If you expect the result to be negative, you will need signed type, like `int`, try this:

```
unsigned int un_i = 1112;
printf ("PRINTF: un_i[%d] and u_i/10[%d]\n", (1 - un_i), (1 - (int)un_i)/10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You expect to print `-1111` and `-111`. However `1 - un_i` produces a result that is also of type *`unsigned int`*; the result is also always non-negative. If `unsigned int` is 32 bits wide (as it is in your case), the result will be `4294966185`; and that divided by 10 would result in `429496618`.

---

The `%d` switch expects a (`signed`) `int`, not an `unsigned int`. Of that  the C11 standard says that when using variable arguments with wrong type the behaviour is undefined, **excepting** that

> one type is a signed integer type, the other type is the corresponding unsigned integer type, **and the value is representable in both types**

---

Thus printing `429496618` with `%d` has defined behaviour, as this same value is representable as both `signed int` and `unsigned int`.

However `1 - 1112U` will have the value of `UINT_MAX - 1110`, which, when used as an argument to `printf` and converted with `%d` will lead to **undefined behaviour** since the `UINT_MAX - 1100` value is not representable as a `signed int`; getting `-1111` printed just happens to be the (**undefined**) behaviour in this case.

---

Since you really want to use signed numbers, then you should declare your variable `un_i` as an `int` instead of `unsigned int`.

In case you expect to do signed math with numbers greater than `int` use `long int` or `long long int` or even better, types such as `int64_t` instead of this unsigned trickery.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my consideration is why:
"1 - un_i"       : prints out -1111
"(1-un_i)/10" :  prints out 429496618

Comment: *"Since you really want to use signed numbers, then declare your variable as an int"* -- Excuse me if I am wrong, but isn't signed overflow / underflow in itself UB?

Comment: @DevSolar of course it is, but there is no signed overflow here, even if `int` had the minimum allowed range of `-32767 ... 32767`.

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is from Signed and Unsigned conversion.

1, In case of `unsigned int un_i = 1112`;

```
(1 - un_i) = 0xfffffba9 /* first bit is 1 */
```

Even the first bit is 1, but `un_i` is `unsigned`, so **it treat the first bit as normal value bit**, so **the first bit will be 0 after division**:

**(1 - un_i)/10 = 0x1999992a     /* first bit is 0 */**

```
 printf ("%d", (1 - un_i)/10);  /* 0x1999992a = 429496618 because Sign bit is 0 */
```

2, In case of `int sig_i = 1112`, **the first bit is treated as Sign bit, and keep it is still 1 (negative) after devision by 10:**

**(1 - sig_i) = 0xfffffba9 /* first bit is 1 */**

**(1 - sig_i)/10 = 0xffffff91 /* first bit is 1 */**

```
printf ("%d", (1 - sig_i)/10); /* 0xffffff91 = -111 because Sign bit is 1 */
```

Please run my code to get the detail result:

```
unsigned int un_i = 1112;
int sig_i = 1112;
printf ("Unsigned \n%d [hex: %x]\n", (1 - un_i), (1 - un_i));
printf ("and %d [hex: %x]\n", (1 - un_i)/10, (1 - un_i)/10);

printf ("Signed \n%d[hex: %x]\n", (1 - sig_i), (1 - sig_i));
printf ("and %d [hex: %x]\n", (1 - sig_i)/10, (1 - sig_i)/10);
```

Result

```
Unsigned 
-1111 [hex: fffffba9]
and 429496618 [hex: 1999992a]
Signed 
-1111[hex: fffffba9]
and -111 [hex: ffffff91]
```

Comment: Thank you so much mr. @PaCuTo